# Special number nth root of 1

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $\epsilon_n \neq 1$ solve $x^n=1$. Show that a number $r>1$ exists, $r \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that:

1. $\epsilon_n^i \neq 1$ for $i=1, \dots , r-1$
2. $\epsilon_n^r =1$
3. $r$ divides $n$ without a remainder.

We know that $\epsilon_n = \cos{\frac{2 \pi k}{n}} + i \sin{\frac{2 \pi k}{n}}, k \in \{1, 2, \dots n-1 \}$ (we exclude $k=0$ since $\epsilon_n \neq 1$).

Now, taking $p$th powers of $\epsilon_n$, we notice that $\epsilon_n = 1$ when $p=n$. So $r = n$ and then it satisfies our conditions.

This, however, seems too basic. The fact that $r=n$ follows almost immediately from the solutions of $x^n = 1$. Am I missing some important part of the question?

**Edit:**

Let's consider powers $\epsilon_n^p = \cos{p\frac{2 \pi k}{n}} + i \sin{p\frac{2 \pi k}{n}}$. This can only equal $1$ if $p\frac{2 \pi k}{n} = 2 \pi l$ where $p,l \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now, the problem boils down to finding the least common multiple $LCM \left(\frac{2 \pi k}{n}, 2 \pi\right)$. This, in turn, is equivalent to finding $LCM(k,n)$. If $k$ and $n$ have no common factors, we have ${LCM(k,n) \over k}=n$. Otherwise ${LCM(k,n) \over k}<n$. We can now set $r={LCM(k,n) \over k} \in \mathbb{Z}$ which satisfies our conditions.

Comment: "Am I missing some important part of the question?" Yes, you are missing the fact that $r$ should be the minimal integer such that $\epsilon^r=1$, not any of them. Furthermore, looking at examples could help... say, $n=6$ and $\epsilon=e^{2i\pi/3}$.

Comment: @Did, I edited my initial question to reflect your suggestions. Would appreciate any comments.

Comment: No guarantee that n/k is an integer. The case in my previous comment is n=6, k=4, did you even check it?

Comment: Yes, I did. Wasn't $k=2$?

Comment: Then try n=6, k=4... **Come on!** Work on your own question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\omega \in \mathbb C$ satisfies $\omega^n=1$, consider $E= \{ k \in \mathbb N : k\ne 0, \omega^k = 1 \}$ and prove:

- $E$ is not empty
- $E$ has a smallest element $r$
- $E = r \mathbb N$